# Are these "Urgent Firefox Update" popups bogus?

Tags: malware, firefox

I've gotten, over the past couple of weeks, at least three screens popping up saying "Urgent Firefox Update".  These are from URL `https://eexowdlzyjx.net/`.  At least once they have been preceded by "request to load" security popups from unknown (and equally obscure) URLs.  All this while browsing the BBC news site.

Am I correct in assuming that these are bogus?

I'm running Mozilla Firefox, version 47.0, and I have Flashblock 1.5.20 installed.  My AV software is Norton Internet Security version 22.6.0.142.

**Update 7/23/2016:**

For some reason today Norton "caught" this, since right after the bogus screens popped up it came up with a warning that it had stopped a virus.  It labels it `pf06aivz.js.part` and calls it a "JS.Downloader".

The bogus screens came up just after I closed a BBC screen, and the bogus web screen loaded over ("pushed down") a CNN screen.  Not sure what that suggests.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't believe this pop up, and scan your computer, you must have a virus.

Comment: @Damien "you must have a virus" - are you sure? maybe a hacked ad-server?

Comment: Indeed, I'm not sure, but it'd be better to scan the computer than do nothing

Comment: @Damien - I take it as being some sort of malicious advert that is being loaded by a "legitimate" page.  A bit disturbing that this happens off of BBC, but I suppose it's hard for them to police thousands of ads.  (I have Norton installed, and it scans daily.)

Comment: They could be opened by some other page that you have open in the background as well in another tab or window.

Comment: @Anders - To my recollection this has only occurred when I was actively browsing BBC, though I'd typically have CNN and Stack Exchange pages up at the same time.  I don't normally have other windows open.

Comment: I've had this on BBC, and just now while reading Dilbert.  Somehow I want to blame the 2016 presidential campaign for this level of malware douchebaggery.

Comment: FWIW, I still get this on occasion.  I seem to get it most often when I've been on CNN, though it may not appear until I'm just leaving that site.  My Norton AV stuff is current, and I've reset my DSL modem and wi-fi router (and cleared my browser cache several times), since someone said there might be a bad page cached somewhere.  Still get it.

Answer (score 4):

Always, always use ad-blockers.  Browsing the web without an ad-blocker is like sex without a condom.  Always use one unless you are 100% sure the site you are browsing has malware-free ads.

I would refrain from clicking on any pop-up, especially in this case, as Firefox auto-updates in the background and requires no user input, unless a browser restart is required.

Comment: *ad*vertisments

Answer (score 2):

When I get it, it's not a pop-up, the page I'm at is replaced by the "Urgent Firefox Update" page and then it immediately tries to download firefox-patch.exe. This has happened to me twice, once I was on eBay and the other time I was on a random local news website. FWIW, I have Flash set to ask permission before loading, so it's not a flash ad doing it. But I do believe it must be an ad somehow calling this malicious website because the only action on my part is possibly scrolling. I'm running AVG with the latest definitions and it doesn't find anything.

[image]

Comment: Yep, this describes what I see.  The screen looks pretty convincing -- I'm sure many people fall for it.

Comment: (Do you recall what sites you were browsing when it occurred?)

Answer (score 1):

Scan your computer. Check your host file for weird entries. I have the habit of using a non-admin windows account and whenever a program wishes to make changes or launch, it will prompt for my admin credentials. This will mitigate any unknown changes from malware. Currently using WebRoot security program because it has a feature of blocking known malicious IP from connecting to your OS.

Always type in the URL if you know rather than clicking on a given link or pop up. You can use your browsers/programs update button to check for legit updates.

Store your data on a separate hard disk away from your system disk if you can. Backup your data regularly, I use a NAS to sync data from my computer like how Dropbox does. So, I will always have two copies of my data.

Also, do not trust these Green Locks or HTTPS seen on your browser easily. It's not difficult to get a certificate or to make a self-signed certificate looks legit (although this method needs an attacker to install a trust cert into your browser first)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a malware or an advertisement popup. Scan your computer and block popups from unwanted websites.